# Optimizing pixel-swapping shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm using a shader that swaps colors/palettes on a texture. The shader checks a pixel for transparency and then sets the pixel if not transparent. Is there an efficient way to ignore 0 alpha pixels other than a potential branch? In this case, where I set `pixel = newPixel`:

```
uniform bool alternate;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main()
{
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(bitmap, openfl_TextureCoordv);

    if(alternate)
    {
        vec4 newPixel = texture2D(texture, vec2(pixel.r, pixel.b));

        if(newPixel.a != 0.0)
            pixel = newPixel;
    }

    gl_FragColor = pixel;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtmlv) and [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml):

```c
void main()
{
    vec4 pixel = texture2D(bitmap, openfl_TextureCoordv);
    vec4 newPixel = texture2D(texture, vec2(pixel.r, pixel.b));
    gl_FragColor = mix(pixel, newPixel, 
                       float(alternate) * (1.0 - step(newPixel.a, 0.0)));
}
```

You may want to make a smooth transition depending on the alpha channel. In this case you only need  [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml):

```c
gl_FragColor = mix(pixel, newPixel, float(alternate) * newPixel.a);
```

Comment: I'm using the shader to recolor a pixel art PNG source graphic that only has a solid color or complete transparency. The first gl_FragColor does not draw the old colors as well (only draws the changed pixels), but the second example you listed appears to be working so far!

Comment: @dinorider Try `step(0.01, newPixel.a)` or `(1.0 - step(newPixel.a, 0.0))`. (`step` only returns 0.0 if *x < edge*)

Comment: Because the second code you posted is simpler than the first and works exactly the same in testing as my old code, I might just opt for it. Do you think this new code without the two branches would result in better performance?

Comment: @dinorider There is nothing to optimize here. You have to measure the performance. The result can vary depending on the hardware and driver. In this case I would just take the shortest code and leave the optimizations to the compiler and driver.

Comment: I'll look into testing, but thank you for the code and help!

Comment: As a followup, when stress testing with a lot of graphics, both the original "branch" code and the new shortened code perform almost identically for various targets. There must be some optimization behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the [step](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) function. You can express the if statement as a product of two conditions.

For example:

```
if (a >= 0) {
  b = c;
}
```

Is equivalent to

```
b = (step(a, 0)*c) + (1.0 - step(a, 0)*b);
```